# Is there an easy way of sorting a plist (array of dictionaries) by key value?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, sorting, plist, nsdictionary

I need to reorder a plist (an array of dictonaries) by Key value.

In this example content I'd like to order by the value for the key Name (Matt, Joe):

```
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Matt</string>
    <key>Details</key>
    <string>Me</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Joe</string>
    <key>Details</key>
    <string>You</string>
</dict>
```

Is there an easy way? I don't want to do it in code each time the app is run, I just want to do it to the data file.

Any ideas?

Happy to use any tool to get this done: ninja parameters for sort on the command line, a plist editor, text editor or whatever.

Comment: Arrays will be stored in order, so store the keys themselves as a separate, ordered array. Whenever you add or remove a key from the dictionary, do the same to the key array and reorder it before you write the plist back to disk.

Comment: If I'm going that way, how do I get the keys in an ordered array?

Comment: Add all the values for name from each dictionary to a mutable array, then call sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) on the array. That will give you a new, sorted array of the name keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a five line PHP script to reorder them. I guess I still have a lot of Cocoa to learn before I can do something that quickly and comfortably with it.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a script in this case, it's probably easier since you wouldn't have to create and build a project just for one task.

Answer (score 12):

This is another coding solution, but it wouldn't be hard to make a basic command line tool that wrapped around it:

```
NSArray* arrayOfDictionaries; //the array we want to sort
NSSortDescriptor* nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortedArray = [arrayOfDictionaries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor]];
[nameSortDescriptor release];
```

Comment: Don't forget to release the sort descriptor after creating the array with it. The iPhone doesn't have GC.

Comment: Release added for great justice :)

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a little Python script that reads from standard input and writes to standard output:

```py
#/usr/bin/env python3

# Save as sortplist.py

import plistlib
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    plist = plistlib.load(f)
xml_bytes = plistlib.dumps(plist, sort_keys=True)
print(str(xml_bytes, 'utf-8'))
```

So, just do `python3 sortplist.py original.plist >sorted.plist`.

The above works with Python 3.4+.  If you need to use an older version of Python, this works with the older `plistlib` API:

```py
# sortplist.py
import plistlib
import sys
    
plist = plistlib.readPlist(sys.stdin)
plistlib.writePlist(plist, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: This has not help sort my app's Info.plist at all. The order of keys in Xcode remain the same and the diff is minimal.

Comment: Sorry, @fatuhoku. The behavior of plistlib may have changed in the years since I wrote this answer. It used to sort them.

Comment: Try "sort_keys": plistlib.dump(value, fp, *, fmt=FMT_XML, sort_keys=True, skipkeys=False)

Comment: Thanks @Alexey. I've updated the answer so that it works with the current Python `plistlib` API. (My original 2012 answer was written for Python 2.x.)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Our key array
NSMutableArray *unsortedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];
// Assume we have some array of dictionaries
for( NSDictionary *dict in dictionaryArray ) {
  NSString *key = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
  if( key )
    [unsortedKeys addObject:key];
}
NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// Do things with the keys...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is your friend: http://effbot.org/zone/element-sort.htm :-)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know Python though. :)

Comment: Ramin, small world - I follow you on Twitter.