# Is there any possible way to get JSON from a PHP web app in order

Tags: php, ios, json

I'm building an IOS app that queries a database. I keep getting the results out of order, and in some functionality in the app, like comments, it's crucial that I get them in order. It's obvious JSON is returning a dict, but I need the results ordered. Here's the server side code:

```
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html') {
  $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
  header($status_header);
  header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
  echo $body;
}

$result = array();
$i = 0;
$sqlGetComments = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM photo_comments WHERE photo_id='$photoID' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlGetComments)) {
  $result[$i] = array(
      'photoID' => $row['photo_id'],
      'userID' => $row['userID'],
      'username' => $row['username'],
      'comment' => $row['comment'],
      'postedDate' => $row['post_date'],
    );
    $i++;
} // end while

sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

I have IOS code that parses that, but out of order from how I need it. So there has to be something I can do server side.

Update, Here is the client side code:

```
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
   [self updateComments:responseString];
}];


- (void)updateComments:(NSString *)update {
     NSDictionary *root = [update JSONValue];
     NSEnumerator *enumerator = [root keyEnumerator];
     id key;
     while (key = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        NSDictionary *value = [root objectForKey:key];
       _photoID = [value objectForKey:@"photoID"];
       NSString *photoID = [value objectForKey:@"photoID"];
       NSString *userID = [value objectForKey:@"userID"];
       NSString *username = [value objectForKey:@"username"];
       NSString *comment = [value objectForKey:@"comment"];
       NSString *postedDate = [value objectForKey:@"postedDate"];

       NSString *cellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@ \n %@", username, comment, postedDate];

       [_queryResultsMessage addObject:cellString];
     }
     [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here's the print out keeping in mind that "Test" string in the comment field is how the JSON string should print out:

```
{"1":{"photoID":"1","userID":"17","username":"kismet","comment":"Test 6","postedDate":"7 hrs ago"},"2":{"photoID":"1","userID":"17","username":"kismet","comment":"Test 5","postedDate":"8 hrs ago"},"3":{"photoID":"1","userID":"17","username":"kismet","comment":"Test 4","postedDate":"8 hrs ago"},"4":{"photoID":"1","userID":"17","username":"kismet","comment":"Test 3","postedDate":"8 hrs ago"},"5":{"photoID":"1","userID":"17","username":"kismet","comment":"Test 2","postedDate":"8 hrs ago"},"6":{"photoID":"1","userID":"17","username":"kismet","comment":"Test 1","postedDate":"8 hrs ago"}}
```

It prints out OK but I'm guessing it's getting jumbled when being assigned to NSDictionary. If nobody has any answers, I'll try to fiddle around with it by assigning it to an NSArray and see if I can parse that somehow.

Comment: what does an actual json encoded version of the result look like? if it is in the order you expect, you may need additional control of your json parsing in the consuming application.

Comment: I am no php man, but it seems obvious that the json should be returning an *array*, not a dictionary. $result is an array.

Comment: Do you need to [`ksort` your array first](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your iOS application cannot consume the data out of order? That seems like a potentially brittle point of an application to leave exposed...

Comment: @sarnold, It's for comments on a photo. This is one of the only things I need from the db in order. The rest of the app, screw it, it can come in any order it wants to.

Comment: @coneybeare, the data does come in an ordered array inside the $result[$i], but each one of those $result[$i] is coming in unordered, like a dictionary.

Comment: so... some of the `$result[$i]` are ordered: `[photoID, userID, username,...]` and another one is ordered `[userID, username, photoID,...]`, and another is ordered `[postedData, comment, ...]`, and so on?

Comment: @sarnold - if I understand correctly, he's getting a NSMutableArray of NSDictionary's - the NSMutableArray isn't in the correct order. Or, in PHP/JSON terms - the order of JSON items is out of order, not individual "child" key/values.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger Can you give us the response jSON String?? the one you are getting in completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little client side IOS hackery was needed

For those who are still interested in the solution:

```
NSDictionary *userData = [update JSONValue];
NSArray *keys = [[userData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [keys count]];

int i = 0;
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    [array addObject: [userData objectForKey: key]];
    i++;
}

for (NSDictionary *myDict in array) {
    NSString *comment = [myDict objectForKey:@"comment"];
    NSLog(@"USERCOMMENT %@", comment);
}
```

Returns JSON all in order:

```
USERCOMMENT Test 6
USERCOMMENT Test 5
USERCOMMENT Test 4
USERCOMMENT Test 3
USERCOMMENT Test 2
USERCOMMENT Test 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that 
- You're requesting the items ordered from MySQL
- Ergo, PHP is generating the JSON in order.

Because of this, I would simply suggest editing the loop in PHP...

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlGetComments)) {
  $result[$i] = array(
      'photoID' => $row['photo_id'],
      'userID' => $row['userID'],
      'username' => $row['username'],
      'comment' => $row['comment'],
      'postedDate' => $row['postedDate'],
      'orderBy' => $i
    );
    $i++;
} // end while
```

... and organising them by "orderBy" in Obj-C.

Note, all I've done is add an extra variable to the JSON items - "orderBy"; as the MySQL results will be in the correct order, and thus are parsed in the correct order, this "orderBy" variable could act like a key.

It's a while since I've worked with the iOS SDK - but I'm pretty sure they will be a method to sort an NSMutableArray; if not - a simple loop could work; requesting each object with the key of x, whilst x < length of NSMutableArray. I'll look up the "correct" way of doing it however, as that will bug me!

**I would suggest investigating the real reason behind the results coming in out of order though! That shouldn't be happening!** I haven't done similar in iOS but  I would assume this isn't the correct behaviour when requesting JSON.

Troubleshooting steps may be checking the returned JSON in-browser or on a desktop environment and ensuring the PHP is returning it correctly, then seeing how it's returned to the app - ensuring all data is present and whether there is a pattern to the distortion of order.

*Edit: I've noticed you're saying it's returning an array of dictionaries. My bad.*
I did find [another question that goes into sorting an array of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864412/is-there-an-easy-way-of-sorting-a-plist-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-value).

Comment: Can you order something from one dictionary key in IOS? These results are being collected from a while loop into an array client side. I don't know how to go inside the array, select one key, and then move that dictionary's position based off that one key in the nsmutablearray hierarchy.

Comment: Off the top of my head, perhaps using some form of loop - however that's not ideal. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a method for this however, as it would seem to be quite a straight forward task. I'll look in some iOS SDK desk references I have laying around.

Comment: Ah, this is where we see the problem. Your json array should not be parsed into a dictionary. IOS code is most likely the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I would suspect it's iOS - simply because PHP *will* be getting the results in the correct order from MySQL, and judging by that code - *will* be returning the JSON correctly. A simple way of verifying it would be to check in-browser. Just out of interest, any chance of you editing the question with some Obj-C from the app? :)

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni. How should I parse it then? Any ideas?

Comment: ok, the JSON you're receiving is fine, and keyed by the (apparently 1-based) array position of the representation in the query results. Your client code should be making an array of dictionaries, rather than nesting dictionaries. 

This is straightforward JSON deserialization, isn't there a library method that will let you go JSON=> Array of Objects in the Foundation library now?

Answer (score 0):

In your MySql query, you are sorting on `post_date`, but then refer to `postedDate` when adding it to your results array. Do both exist?

If `post_date` does not in fact exist then your database query is not sorting as you expect...

Comment: The JSON you've posted appears to be sorted correctly. So I doubt  there's more you can do server-side. Presumably something is up in how you are parsing it in iOS... but can't help you there :)